# vaex: Check for equality between two frames

Tags: python, unit-testing, vaex

Does `vaex` have any utility functions that help with checking for equality between two dataframes?

For example: `pandas` has `pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal` to check if two frames hold the same columns and values, which is rather nice when writing unit tests. Is there something similar in `vaex`? Or maybe there is another convenient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no utility, but I think it's a good idea to have (If you care, you could open an issue at https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/issues):

A short version would be (ignoring NaN's):

```
import vaex
df1 = vaex.example()
df2 = vaex.example()

df = df1.join(df2, rprefix='rhs_')  # join based on rows number
column_names = df1.get_column_names()
equal = all((df[name] != df["rhs_" + name]).sum() == 0 for name in column_names)
print(equal)

True
```